# Re-sizing an image which in Base64 format and converting to Base64 again in java

Tags: java, image, base64, image-resizing

I was wondering if there is a way to read a string which is a Base64 representation of an image and resize it (scale down actually). After that converting it to Base64 again. 
At the moment, to encode an image into a Base64 string I am using the `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` library.

Comment: Base64-decode the image, use ImageIO to read it, use Java2D to scale it, ImageIO to encode it, and then base64 encode it again.